# Is Ergo a renowned journal?

Tags: publications

I was looking for a journal to publish an article on metaphysics and I found the [Ergo site](https://www.ergophiljournal.org), which offers triple-blind peer review and free access to articles.

However, I was unable to retrieve any information about the quality of the journal, nor its impact factor.
Is the journal renowned?

Answer (score 3):

I'd say so. [Brian Leiter held a poll in 2018](https://leiterreports.typepad.com/blog/2018/11/best-general-journals-of-philosophy-2018.html) to find the best 'general' journals of philosophy and Ergo came in 17th, which is quite good.

Also, for what it's worth, I've found that the impact factor of philosophy journals isn't a good metric for determining journal quality. Philosophers tend to not cite very much.